# Delete non-numerical values - Unix

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, sed

I have a file where I only need numbers [0-9]. I have this command `sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` which deletes anything that's not [0-9] but I need to only delete things left of a ","

I have this now, but it isn't working how I'd think it should...

```
sed -ri "s/[^0-9]+\,/,/g"
```

Comment: I now have `sed -ri 's/[^0-9].*,/,/' ` which deletes anything from the first non-numerical number up until the ","  which looks like this 13513asdf4134,344 to 13513,344 when I need it to look like 135134134,344

Comment: I would have expected `'s/[^0-9].\(.*,\)/\1/g'` to work, but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Any idea what to try? I've been trying a bunch of different things but nothing seems to work. @Beta

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment above, I don't understand why `'s/[^0-9].\(.*,\)/\1/g'` doesn't work, but there are alternatives.

We can use `t` (test) to do what I expected `g` to do:

```
sed -e:a -e 's/[^0-9].\(.*,\)/\1/;ta'
```

Or use the hold space (overkill, but it works):

```
sed 'h;s/.*,/,/;x;s/,.*//;s/[^0-9].//g;G;s/\n//'
```

Comment: That works great, but it deletes one digit after any letter. `12345abcd6789,123` will go to `12345789,123` and lose the 6 for some odd reason. @Beta

Comment: @AdamHorn: These commands don't delete the 6 for me. Do you know which version of sed you're using? We could do some experiments...

Comment: How do I find out what version of sed I'm using? @Beta

Comment: @AdamHorn: It's usually determined by the OS. I've heard some versions support `sed -V`. Anyway, try `sed 's/[0-9]./X/'` and tell us the result.